# If x and y are cointegrated, and too y and z, does this mean x and z are also cointregrated

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Cointegration question.

If x and y are cointegrated, and too y and z, does this mean x and z are also cointregrated.

x, y and z are I(1), the linear combination of x,y is I(0), and the linear combination of y,z is also I(0),

So will the linear combination of x and z also be I(0) and hence cointegrated.

Comment: No, it your method, if log GDP earth and log Consumption on earth are cointegrated. Also log consumption on earth and log GDP on Romulus are cointegrated. Does this make log GDP on Romulus cointegrated with log consumption on earth?

Comment: @user22485: I think, in your last sentence, you meant log GDP on earth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two pairwise cointegrations implies the third one.

Consider the simple case of $\{x_t\}$, $\{y_t\}$ and $\{z_t\}$ each being I(1). If $\{x_t\}$ and $\{y_t\}$ are cointegrated, they share a common stochastic trend and there is no other stochastic trend in $\{x_t\}$ or $\{y_t\}$ that they do not share. The same with $\{z_t\}$ and $\{y_t\}$. Therefore, $\{x_t\}$ and $\{z_t\}$ share a common stochastic trend and there is no other stochastic trend in $\{x_t\}$ or $\{z_t\}$ that they do not share. Thus, $\{x_t\}$ and $\{z_t\}$ are cointegrated.

In the more general case of $\{x_t\}$, $\{y_t\}$ and $\{z_t\}$ each being I(d) with $d>0$, similar logic holds but the formulation gets a bit more involved.

For another perspective of the same thing, see @whuber's elegant proof in the comment.

Comment: This doesn't sound like [the standard definition of cointegration.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration)  But it does look like you're right: if there exist nonzero constants $\alpha,\ldots,\delta$ for which $u=\alpha x+\beta y\sim I(0)$ and $v=\gamma y + \delta z\sim I(0),$ then $\alpha\gamma x - \beta \delta z = \gamma u - \beta v$ is a nonzero linear combination of $I(0)$ processes, *QED.*

Comment: @whuber, I like the constructive approach to cointegration, i.e. thinking about the underlying common stochastic trends. I think the two perspectives (mine and what you refer to as the standard definition) are equivalent, but perhaps my phrasing is not rigorous enough. In any case, your comment contains a beautiful proof.